# CNN low accuracy cats vs dogs dataset

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, keras, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network

I have a train folder, which contains cats folder (5000 pics inside it) and dogs folder (4000 pics inside it). Also, I have a test folder, which contains cats folder (2500 pics) and dogs folder (2000 pics). I have written the below code to apply CNN image classification

Code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,Activation,MaxPooling2D,Dense,Flatten,Dropout
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),input_shape=(64,64,3)))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3)))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2,2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(64))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(1))
classifier.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
classifier.summary()
classifier.compile(optimizer ='rmsprop',
                   loss ='binary_crossentropy',
                   metrics =['accuracy'])
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale =1./255,
                                   shear_range =0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip =True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

batchsize=500
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/osboxes/Downloads/dogs-vs-cats/train/',
                                                target_size=(64,64),
                                                batch_size= batchsize,
                                                class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/osboxes/Downloads/dogs-vs-cats/test/',
                                           target_size = (64,64),
                                           batch_size = batchsize,
                       shuffle=False,
                                           class_mode ='binary')
history=classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                        steps_per_epoch =9000/batchsize,
                        epochs = 3,
                        validation_data =test_set,
                        validation_steps = 4500/batchsize)

Y_pred = classifier.predict_generator(test_set, 4500 / batchsize)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(test_set.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = ['cats', 'dogs']
print(classification_report(test_set.classes, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
# summarize history for loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

The resulted confusion matrix was:

Confusion Matrix

[[2500    0]

[2000    0]]

My questions are:

1- Why all the dogs instances were classified as cat

2- Is it OK to have different samples number between the cats and dogs training folder? Or testing folder? Or they must be exactly the same?

3- How can I add a multi class classifier if I need to add for example horse pictures?

Comment: Why did you train the model for only three epochs?

Comment: for speed purposes only. Shall I go for 20 or more?

Comment: Yes, you are not correctly training a model (3 epochs is not enough) and that is why the model produces bad predictions.

Comment: I tried 50 epochs and got the same confusion matrix results

Comment: Is the loss decreasing across epochs? Also a batch size of 500 is kind of insane, try something like 64 or 128.

Comment: The accuracy has enhanced when using 50 epochs and the loss has dropped. My concern is the confusion matrix. I think I am missing something in my code?

Answer (score 0):

1- Because you put `classifier.add(Dense(1))` that means you have only one class. Since you have two, you must put `classifier.add(Dense(2))` and change your loss to `loss ='categorical_crossentropy'`

2- Yes a little difference between the number of images in each class is OK (but it shouldn't be so much difference)

3- Change the loss as I said and put `classifier.add(Dense(3))`

And it's better to use **Adam optimizer** and also use `BatchNormalization()` before each `Activation()` function.

Comment: No, one unit with sigmoid activation can be used for binary classification if you use the binary crossentropy loss.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro You're right, I heard about that before, but never tried. What's the advantage of using binary in 2-class classification?

Comment: for a classification with two classes, binary classification with dense = 1 is recommended. As optimizer Adam is fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must set `shuffle=False` for `test_datagen.flow_from_directory` function, otherwise, it will shuffle your test dataset and confusion matrix spoil. You made it, OK.
2. Replace `y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)` with `y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5).astype(int)`

   ```
   #y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)  # for 'categorical' class_mode
   y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5).astype(int)  # for 'binary' class_mode
   ```